# "Start A Bounty" link still shows up even after an answer is accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

Title speaks for itself. Why give the ability to offer a bounty when the question is already solved?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.

See:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: hm. weird. so basically, if someone isn't satisfied by the accepted answer, they can "re-initiate" the question for a more satisfying answer? is that the idea?

Comment: The user adding the bounty isn't necessarily the OP. Alternatively, the OP may just want to offer a "tip" to answer even though they've already accepted one.